# Python video processing with buffer - error when executing two threds

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, video

I'm starting with openCv and threads for video processing.

In this case the test is done with a mp4 video, but the intention is to do it from an IP camera. Since I can not control the FPS that my video source gives me and my idea is to add processing, what I do is work in the following way:

- A main thread takes the frames of my source and pushes them into a FIFO (it's my input buffer)
- From another thread what I do is take out the frames to process them and control the frame dropping.

I did a test with the following code but I can not get it to work correctly, for a moment it works, after that my computer stops responding so I guess it's a memory problem.

```
import threading, time
import cv2
import queue

input_buffer = queue.Queue()

def processing():
    while True:
        if not input_buffer.empty():
            print("get")
            frame=input_buffer.get()
            cv2.imshow("Video",frame)
            time.sleep(0.025)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    return

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videoplayback.mp4')
t = threading.Thread(target=processing)
t.start()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret and not input_buffer.full():
        input_buffer.put(frame)
        print("put")
```

Would you help me see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some things I edited:

- First of all: You did not define a *maxsize* for the queue, so checking if it is full doesn't do anything, since there is always room.
- `get(..)` just blocks the thread if there is no item until it finds one, so no need to check if there is any
- You should let the `while` loop in the main thread also have a little `sleep(0.025)` otherwise it will just constantly fill up the queue

With these changes I was able to play mp4. Hopefully now you are, too.

```
import threading, time
import cv2
import queue

input_buffer = queue.Queue()

def processing():
    while True:
        print("get")
        frame=input_buffer.get()
        cv2.imshow("Video",frame)
        time.sleep(0.025)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    return

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videoplayback.mp4')
t = threading.Thread(target=processing)
t.start()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    input_buffer.put(frame)
    time.sleep(0.025)
    print("put")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifications and corrections.

I did not know that behavior of the queues in python, I come a little more accustomed to C.

Now it works, really thanks!